# How to know the current state of application invoked in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is it possible to know the state of application invoked in blackberry? For example, if we invoke blackberry email application after sending an email, can we know if the application has closed or still running and also where the email has been sent, the subject, the content, etc.? The code may be something like this:

```
try {
    Message message = new Message();
    Address address = new Address("email@yahoo.com", "Email");
    Address[] addresses = {address};
    message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, addresses);
    message.setContent("Testing email from MyTabViewDemo application");
    message.setSubject("Testing Email");
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(message));
    log.debug(MyApp.GUID_LOG, "Send email action done!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Dialog.inform(e.toString());
}
```

and how about retrieving the state of other applications like phone, sms, camera?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the visible applications by calling

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getVisibleApplications();
```

That returns an array of application descriptors. From a descriptor, you can know the names and ids.

It is possible, however, that the messaging app is always on background and cannot be closed (I'm not 100% sure here)

But you can't know if a message has ben sent or not sending the mail like that.